# How to use Dynamic height on UITableviewCell with Image fetched from Afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have written an app that fetches images from Facebook and displays them in Custom UITableViewCells.

Within the cell there's two labels, a small image and a larger image that is fetched from facebook through AFNetworking like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
.....
[cell.pic setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                images[indexPath.row] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",image.size.height];
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            }];
```

The image is also added to an array that is there to decide the height.
After that the tableview is reloaded to apply the new height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                return [images[indexPath.row] floatValue] + 80;
```

Scrolling works flawlessly and the images load as intended when scrolling downwards but as soon as you scroll up this happens:

Error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WY8vnWC.png]

Normal:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Lkrs4MF.png]

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Thanks :)

Note that this app is just for testing purposes

Comment: Have you tried using NSNumber instead of NSString? `images[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.height];`

Comment: try to colorise every cell with diffirent color to see better

Comment: Same result using NSNumber I'm afraid :/ Both the refreshview and tableviewbackground is white so it has to do with the Cell itself.

Comment: give each cell diffirent bg color yellow,blue

Comment: When scrolling down everything is perfect, colors made it easier to see :) when I scroll back up and then down again this happens though http://imgur.com/a/xd0hw#0

Comment: Hello, Did you solve above issue. I am also facing same problem. Can you help me?